# Emacs , use-package and package-refresh-contents

Tags: emacs, package, emacs24

In my init.el I want use "use-package" to lazily load my mode and speed up my emacs start.

I want use-package automatically download my mode from elpa/melpa/... thanks to package lib.

But it seems I need to do a (package-refresh-contents) before each time otherwise  use-package raise an error.

```
(error "Package `deft' is not available for installation")
```

my conf is

```
(require 'use-package)
(package-refresh-contents) ; take forever at each emacs start
(use-package deft 
  :ensure t)
```

but (package-refresh-contents) take forever.
can't we delegate the (package-refresh-contents) to use-package so it is done once ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`use-package` does not provide this functionality.  You could use the following instead:

```
(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))
```

This will only update the package list, if it is empty, which should be sufficient to avoid your problem.  You still need to manually update packages, though, with `M-x list-packages` and `U`.

Comment: thks, I tried this syntax and the very first time emacs is used with this config with a fresh new .emacs.d/ I also had the error. From what you wrote this is normal, as I did not refresh package list. It seems to me that even I I had refreshed the package list the refresh occurs every time...